# How to make muitifile addon?

Tags: python, add-on, import

I'm trying to learn how to create a multifile addon, but its getting hard, I've tried out some ways but no sucess. the method that better worked was this.
but it is giving me an error on line 17 now 
`'TypeError: ("reload() argumment must be module")'`
someone can help?

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "driven_shapes",
    "description": "",
    "author": "Your Name",
    "version": (0, 0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 78, 0),
    "location": "View3D",
    "warning": "This addon is still in development.",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Object" }


if "bpy" in locals():
    import importlib


    importlib.reload("shapesplit")
    importlib.reload("driver_add")
    importlib.reload("ui")
else:
    from . import shapesplit
    from . import driver_add
    from . import ui

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the TypeError because of passing a string argument to the *reload* function. *reload* function expects a module object as its argument.

You could create a mapping of the modules you want reloaded and then pass the mapping's value to reload.

You can refer to an example from Blender's UI module for a thorough example.

[scripts/startup/bl_ui/**init**.py](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/startup/bl_ui/__init__.py;420d4a70b8febfdfdab253c5d814aef5bb57dda0$26)

[image: reloading modules]

[image: building a mapping of modules to reload]

Comment: That is great. In general I have found Blender's factory Python scripts to be of high quality and a great resource to learn from.